# how can i make divs rorate but not the content in it?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i can rotate the div or implement the clip-path property on to it. but i am not getting desire results with my approach. i have searched the codepen and other results from google search but nada.

i have used clip-path and skew property on the div but again i think i am not following the correct approach.i want to make my div lie on to each other with appropriate spacing and in the skew state as you can see.

i want it like that......
[here is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClAr4.png)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The content rotates along the parent element. You've to rotate the content to the other direction to make it stay in place.

Comment: clip-path: polygon(0 10%, 100% 0%, 100% 90%, 0% 100%); on to the divs.       and then skew on to parent and then opposite skew to child div... of course 2 different approaches and then I even combined them.

Comment: @usmannoor90 attach some of your html and css

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this, I used `transform` property to do it:

```css
.flexContainer {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexContainer>* {
    flex: 0 0 33%;
}

.theContainer {
    margin: 0 0.5em;
    padding: 2em 2em 7em 2em;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ededed;
    transform: skew(0, -5deg);
}

.theContainer.first {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

.theContent {
  position: absolute;
  transform: skew(0, 5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
  <div class="theContainer first">
    <div class="theContent">
      <h2> Title </h2>
      <p> Content test </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="theContainer second">
    <div class="theContent">
      <h2> Title </h2>
      <p> Content test </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="theContainer first">
    <div class="theContent">
      <h2> Title </h2>
      <p> Content test </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="theContainer second">
    <div class="theContent">
      <h2> Title </h2>
      <p> Content test </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes that was great. but again let me check that on to my elements.

Comment: nope, it did rotate but i think it needs to be extended on the opposite edges and shrunk on the other edges.

Comment: Could you share what you have tried

Comment: Check the update that I did, Is that what you need? if I understand well what you want

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1>4</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    transform: skew(0, -6deg);
  }
  .container .item {
    text-align: center;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  .container .item h1 {
    transform: skew(0, 6deg);
  }
</style>
```